# BottomNavigationView item scroll

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to do a BottomNavigationView but it is displayed as a scroll menu. I'm trying to have something like this:
Image1:
[image: Image1]

But it appears like this in my project: Image2:
[image: Image2]

I have the main XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".PostOrSearch">


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="420dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    design:menu="@menu/manu_layout"
    />
```

And the menu XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:title="Perfil"
    android:icon="@drawable/perfil"/>

<item
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon = "@drawable/search"/>
<item
    android:title="Post"
    android:icon = "@drawable/megaphone"/>
```

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and [the tagging guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Comment: Add full xml code of `menu` and `activity`. Currently both of them have wrong syntax.

Comment: you need to use `BottomNavigationView` to achieve that you declare above.Not `NavigationView` .

Comment: @ParthLotia yup! it worked. Really stupid error i had there. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Marco Happy to help...